# jQuery Auto Complete Return Data - Showing the ID aswell as label

Tags: php, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using Codeigniter to create an Autocomplete for user names:

Using the parameter : search-user?term=s I get the following data back as Json :

```
{"id":"1","value":"Stuart Blackett"}{"id":"2","value":"Simon Wilton"}
```

[image]

However when I am running the auto select, On the search for say "St" it brings back by name in the options, But also the ID as well.

How do I prevent this from happening? I suspect my loop could be the issue.

My PHP Function is as follows :

```
function search_user()
    {
            $term = $this->input->get('term');

            $user_search = $this->vendor_model->search_user($term);

            $user['response'] = 'false';

            if(count($user_search) > 0)
            {
                $user['response'] = 'true';
                $user = array();
                foreach($user_search as $user)
                {
                    $user = array(
                        'id'        => $user->user_id,
                        'value' => $user->user_firstname .' '. $user->user_surname
                    );

                    echo json_encode($user);
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: What's the value of `$user_search`?

Comment: An echo of count($user_search) for the term='s' is 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{"id":"1","value":"Stuart Blackett"}{"id":"2","value":"Simon Wilton"}` isn't valid JSON.

Try not echoing each `$user`'s information separately - instead, build a new array of `users` and `json_encode()` that array. Example:

```
foreach($user_search as $user) {
    $users[] = array(
        'id'    => $user->user_id,
        'value' => $user->user_firstname .' '. $user->user_surname
    );
}

echo json_encode($users);
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks @jterry I will know in future to also check if the json is valid or not. Cheers

Comment: Glad to help! Also helpful for the future, [`json_last_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) is really nice to have for debugging PHP JSON functions. An accept if this solution worked for you would be appreciated :)

Comment: json_last_error Seems like quite a useful error trapper in JSON. Thanks. Accepted your solution